# How to run the client side script on textchange event of textbox?

Tags: asp.net

Suppose You have TextBox Control and the user enter any key into it. When the user enter the key ,on that event the key which is pressed stored into array and show him any another character.

Example . suppose i enter "x" but the textbox should display me "p".

Comment: Can you explain, what's the purpose of confusing users like this?

Comment: What are you trying to do with something like this?  It seems like it would be frustrating for the users...

Comment: Simple cipher homework maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need some JavaScript! With this code no matter what key the user presses, the textbox will type out ‘p.’ You could mix in a random letter generator if you really want to get crazy.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">        
    function ScrewyKeypad(evt) {
        var info = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>').value;
        document.getElementById('<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>').value = info + 'p'
        return false;
    }
```

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" onkeypress="return ScrewyKeypad(event)" ></asp:TextBox>
```

And be sure to register the script in your page load event:

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        TextBox2.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return ScrewyKeypad(event)");            
    }
```